# How to get information about Windows update status via wmic or nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cmd, wmic

I need information if the Windows updates status is ok and return it

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve] even if not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nodejs has plenty of functions out of the box that allow you to interface with the operating system. I also found this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) that provides even more functionality, maybe something in there can help you.